# How can my app access touch events while running in the background?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"Entered1");

    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]){

        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) {
            UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

            __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;

            background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            [application endBackgroundTask:background_task];

            background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

        }];


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue
                       (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                           NSLog(@"Running background");

        //Calling method from ViewController


        [application endBackgroundTask:background_task];
        background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                       });

        }
    }
```

I want to call class `ViewController.m` from `AppDelegate.m` so as I might calculate finger position on screen and size while in the background and application is minimized. Thus it must determine all values on accessing different windows and applications on screen. Until now ViewController is able to find these values on single window. Please suggest the logic to implement the same. Can we just call these methods from AppDelegate, if so how?

The methods declared in `ViewContoller.m` code is as follows,

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


    NSLog(@"Filename =%@", inputText);

    UITouch *theTouch = [touches anyObject];
    startPoint = [theTouch locationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat x = startPoint.x;
    CGFloat y = startPoint.y;
    xCoord.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@ "x = %f", x];
    yCoord.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@ "y = %f", y];


    //Calculating finger size in millimeters-

    locate = [[theTouch valueForKey:@"pathMajorRadius"] floatValue];
    value.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pressure = %.2f", locate];
 }

 - (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

     UITouch *theTouch = [touches anyObject];
     CGPoint touchLocation = [theTouch locationInView:self.view];
     CGFloat x = touchLocation.x;
     CGFloat y = touchLocation.y;
     xCoord.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@ "x = %f", x];
     yCoord.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@ "y = %f", y];

     locate = [[theTouch valueForKey:@"pathMajorRadius"] floatValue];
     value.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pressure = %.2f", locate];
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *theTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint endPoint = [theTouch locationInView:self.view];
    xCoord.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@ "x:%f, y:%f", startPoint.x, startPoint.y];
    yCoord.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@ "x:%f, y:%f", endPoint.x, endPoint.y];

    locate = [[theTouch valueForKey:@"pathMajorRadius"] floatValue];
    value.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pressure = %.2f", locate];

    dist_x = (endPoint.x - startPoint.x);
    dist_y = (endPoint.y - startPoint.y);

    EucDistance = sqrtf((dist_x * dist_x) + (dist_y * dist_y));
    NSLog(@"Distance =%f", EucDistance);
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Android?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. Only on-screen `UIView` instances will receive touches.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, or why. iOS implements a touch interface where on-screen UIView instances receive touch events. If you don't have a view on the screen, you don't have something that can be touched. It sounds like what you are trying to do is snoop on a user while they are using another app.

Comment: Yes to the some extend I wish to implement the same. I don't want to bound my class to only single view, instead it runs at the background like any other application such as Audio or VOIP. So what I am doing now is to snoop user on multiple screen. Is it possible to call whole class or at least 3 main methods declared in ViewController.m class in AppDelegate.m? Thanks for continued consideration.

Comment: Apple cares about the privacy of its users, and it will not allow you to do that.